# How can I return vertex of the list on Dr Racket?

Tags: racket

I am trying to get vertex on the Racket. But I could not

what am I missing?

```
    (define-struct node (vertex val left right))
(define (list-tree) (make-node 5 'a (make-node 1 'b empty empty) (make-node 6 'c empty (make-node 14 'd empty empty))))



(define (find-level T)
  (+ (node-vertex T) (node-vertex (node-left T) 
  
  )))

(find-level 'd)
```

output is: node-vertex: expects a node, given 'd

how can i get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give a name to the node when you create it.

```
(define-struct node (vertex val left right))  ; define what node means
(define d (make-node 14 'd empty empty))      ; make a node and name it d

(define a-tree 
  (make-node 5 'a (make-node 1 'b empty empty) 
                  (make-node 6 'c empty d)))  ; use the name d here


(define (find-level T)
   (+ (node-vertex T) (node-vertex (node-left T))))

(find-level d)  ; use the name d here
```

I have now shown how to name a node and use it else where.
I haven't checkked whether find-level does what you want.